# Тип данных ltree Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Не могу понять определение из [документации](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/ltree) Postgres:
"Модуль ltree предоставляет несколько типов данных:
   - ltree;
   - lquery;
   - ltextquery."
Как у одного поля может быть несколько типов данных?
Когда необходимо создать поле ltreePath, мы ведь указываем, что тип данных будет **ltree**, при чем тут lquery и textquery?
Это ошибка или я чего-то не понимаю)?

Comment: У одного поля не может быть нескольких типов. Поле имеет **тип** `ltree` из одноимённого **модуля** `ltree`, а `lquery` и `ltextquery` - это типы запроса к полям типа `ltree`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо! Т.е. в доке ошибка

Comment: Нет там ошибки. Модуль предоставляет несколько типов. Но поле может иметь только один из них.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Совсем запутался. Создал таблицу со столбцом с типом данных lquery. Наполнил некоторыми данными. Никакой оператор не работает с lquery.